# How to get scores along with Machine Learning results?

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to machine learning and I am currently working on classification problem. I am able to train the model and predict test data sets. I want to know whether is there some way by which I can get scores along with the prediction. By scores , I mean those are proximity scores along with prediction. For example, in standard age-salary-buy (based on age and salary whether the customer will buy the product or not) classification problem, I want to know what is a score out of 100 that he will buy that product in addition to the prediction of whether he will buy it or not.

Currently, I am using LibSVM Algo. Is there some algo which provides me above data ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a **support** of your decision. In other words, many classifiers base their decision of `x` class over labels `Y` on:

```
cl(x) = arg max_{y \in Y} p(y|x)
```

where `p(y|x)` is their internal estimation of "x having label y". And such classifiers include:

- neural networks (with sigmoid output)
- logistic regression
- naive bayes
- voting ensembles (such as RF)
- ...

These methods can be easily converted to your 0-100 scale, as probability is in 0-1 scale.

Some, on the other hand use measure proportional to probability (such as SVM), but unbounded, here you can get this value (often called decision function) but you cannot convert it to 0-100 score (as you do not have "maximum" value). This is a big drawback, so some modification were proposed. In particular for SVM you have Platt's scaling which actually fits a logistic regression on top of SVM so you get your probability estimate.  In `libSVM` you can set `-b` to get probability estimates

from [libsvm website](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/)

> -b probability_estimates: whether to train a SVC or SVR model for probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0)